# How to change Explorer/File Chooser "File name" and "Save as type" font in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, fonts

I'm using Windows 10 64-bit with "ClearType" off and system font is set to "Tahoma" by changing registry entries. Fonts like Arial, Tahoma looks superb on my system. But there are several problems - in "Save as" file chooser (part of Explorer I think) window - 2 fields - "File name" and "Save as type" - use different font:
[image] 
Those two fields are blurry, hard to read. Is it possible to change the font by changing registry or maybe there is some other way?

Comment: How did you find the other registry entries? Maybe look further into that direction.

Comment: The font to Tahoma was changed system wide..

Comment: With the exception of you showing that it apparently wasn't. So including what you actually did might provide some more possible clues.

Comment: At first I changed system font manually by substituting Segoe fonts with Tahoma in registry, later I was using Winaero Tweaker. But threre is no difference I think if I've done it manually or by using Winaero Tweaker.

Comment: As a starting point [Winaero Reset Open and Save As Dialog in Windows 10](http://winaero.com/blog/reset-open-save-dialog-windows-10/)